# Open Source DBMS that is similar to Fox Pro

Tags: database

Data entry in my place of work has been going on with fox pro but it is quit an old application and i am trying to figure out an open source alternative where i will be able to replicate most of what is being done on fox pro already. 
Can anyone please recommend a good alternative? 
I think Visual Fox Pro uses Dbase Programming Language and i am not really well informed on it. This wikipedia article describes it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_FoxPro. It's Probably insufficient so i am going to describe the kind of data we enter.

We use it to entered data on daily activities of mammals such as Eating, sleeeping, playing etc. I also use it to enter data on ranging activities and so in a single day i can have a sheet with nearly 50 entries. The date changes per sheet so i want a dbsm that will allow me to enter the date once and not 50 times for each sheet, and when i move to the next sheet i can change the date once and the date is similar for the next 50 entries. I also want to be able to restrict the number of entries in a field.
Sorry my description is probably insufficient but i am a complete novice to this site and to using databases

Comment: As a one-time FoxPro developer, it appears from your question that you are using some kind of interface, not interacting directly with FoxPro tables.  For any other DBMS you might switch to, a similar interface would have to be developed.  So the type of development skills that your or your colleagues have, or can hire, is important to be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Note: I have never used FoxPro)

I once played around with [Symphytum](https://github.com/giowck/symphytum#symphytum) and for a simple "Contact/Address" database it looked quite nice.

It uses SQLite in the background, so even if you ditch the tool at some point, you can at least still access your data (and maybe even use it with a different GUI tool - but I did not look into the database structures in detail).